# How to create physical queue in JMS at run time

Tags: jms

Want to know how to create physical queue in JMS at run time.
when I search for this I got [Creating JMS Queues at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529091/creating-jms-queues-at-runtime)

But when I read http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html I come to know queue which mention in [Creating JMS Queues at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529091/creating-jms-queues-at-runtime) is not creating any physical queue at server side.

Please correct me if I m wrong. If any one know to create physical queue at run time please replay.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of "normal" queues is not adressed by the JMS standard. Depending on what you want to do there are two approaches:

- use temporary queues -> however they have many restrictions, most commonly they are used forrequest-reply scenarios
- use the API of the JMS provider - however your solution will be depending on this specific provider then

Answer (score 0):

The JMS standard only addresses sending and receiving data from objects like queues and topics. Creation of JMS artefacts is vendor specific and most often requires using:

1)specific vendor APIs (not JMS)

2)command/admin messages aimed at the JMS server (command agents on activemq)

3)JMX API

I have used JMX method, which is the most powerful, but also the most work.

### **JMX Method for activemq (version 5.0+)**

**a) JMS Server Setup**

1) Enable JMX in activemq startup scripts and activemq.xml files

2) If you are authenticating to to the server, make sure your user has **admin** privileges setup in activemq.xml (see http://activemq.apache.org/security.html)

3)restart activemq server

**b) Your Client Code**

1) create an instance of `org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean` (you will need to connect with some JMX connectivity code which is a bit messy)

2) use its `addQueue` method. This will create a queue on the server

(The process is similar for hornetq but since you mentioned Activemq I have omitted hornetq details here.)

I have used this method myself and it works.

An alternative is to use **Command Agents** in Activemq, but I have no personal experience with these. These are special messages contain admin commands and may do what you want as well.